Image doesnt send from node.js to React App
This is the node.js part i am trying to get working
app.get('/getimage', (req, res) => {
    const imageName = req.query.name; // Assuming the image name is provided in the query parameter 'name'
    console.log("image name is ", imageName)
    // Construct the path to the image file based on the name
    const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, 'ppics', `${imageName}.jpg`);
    console.log(imagePath);
    // Check if the file exists
    if (fs.existsSync(imagePath)) {
        // Send the image file as a response
        res.sendFile(imagePath);
    } else {
        // If the file doesn't exist, send a 404 response
        res.status(404).send("Image not found");
    }
});

The code has no error and i know the path is right because when i search for the imagepath in file explorer the image shows up. I am trying to receive the image in my react app through this (it's part of a bigger script)
const imageDataResponse = await axios.get(`http://192.168.1.2:3000/getimage?name=${value}`); 

setimage(imageUrl);


and load it here
const [image, setImage] = useState("");

 const refreshhomepage = () => {
    refreshhp(setImage); 
  };

{image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 75, height: 75 }} />}  


For some reason even when there is already an image loaded, and i run this the image vanishes some seconds later as if it receives a null statement, any help?
I was expecting that the image fetched from the Node.js server would be properly set in the React component's state and displayed without disappearing shortly after loading.

Set uri directly on Image, no need to load, the component does it. Something like this:
<Image 
  source={{ uri: `http://192.168.1.2:3000/getimage?name=${value}` }} 
  style={{ width: 75, height: 75 }} 
/>

